Is there some command or api to see which browser version was installed for a specific playwright version?
I would like to know which browser versions where installed by Playwright after running npx playwright install —with-deps chromium firefox
Is there some command to see that or is there some playwright api that returns me the browser versions of a certain playwright version?

There is currently no option on the Playwright command line interface that will return the information you require.
I know it does output the versions when you run the playwright install —with-deps chromium firefox command:
\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\chromium-1097
\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\firefox-1438

And that of course can also been seen on the filesystem in that location, but other than that, or checking the release notes, I don't believe you can access it the information you require any other way.
Note: useless but you can also get the browser version from the browser fixure: browser.version()
